# display list of user .pug js

Tags: javascript, pug, backend

I want to display all the doctors from the database as a list, I don't know how to use list in pug, and how can I display doctor information for each doctor, here where I arrived,please any help , what should i edit or add

```
app.get("/user/new_diagnosis",checkNotAuthenticated,(req, res) => {
    res.render("user-diagnosis",{ name: req.user.userName ,surname: req.user.userSurname });
    db.query(
      `SELECT * FROM doctor`,
        (err, results) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
           const Ndoc = results;
           console.log(results);
        }
      );
  });
```

console.log(results); output

```
[
  RowDataPacket {
    doctorID: 1,
    hospitalName: 'momi',
    doctorName: 'adam',
    doctorSurname: 'rakii',
    doctorEmail: 'adam.rakii@gmail.com',
    doctorPassword: 'riro',
    created_at: null,
    updated_at: null
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    doctorID: 2,
    hospitalName: 'hopi',
    doctorName: 'hajar',
    doctorSurname: 'rako',
    doctorEmail: 'hajar.hu@gmail.com',
    doctorPassword: 'dsj',
    created_at: null,
    updated_at: null
  }
]
```

```
extends user-layout 

block content 
    div.container-fluid
        div(class=["row", "pt-4"])
            div(class=["col-md-3", "col-sm-5", "d-md-flex", "flex-column", "border-end"])
                h3(class=["text-black", "py-4", "text-center"]) Select A Doctor
                form.d-flex.mb-3(role="form", action="/", method="get")
                    input.form-control.me-2(id="doctor-search", name="doctor-search", type='search' placeholder='Search' aria-label='Search')
                    button.btn.btn-outline-success(type='submit') Search
                - var doctor_number = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
                each val in doctor_number
                    .list-group
                        a.list-group-item.list-group-item-action.d-flex.gap-3.py-3(href= `new_diagnosis/${val}`, aria-current='true')
                            svg(xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", width="50", height="50", fill="currentColor", class=["bi", "bi-person-circle", "pe-1"], viewBox="0 0 16 16")
                                path(d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z")
                                path(fill-rule="evenodd", d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z")
                            .d-flex.gap-2.w-100.justify-content-between
                                div
                                    h6.mb-0= "Doctor "+ val
                                    p.mb-0.opacity-75 Some placeholder content in a paragraph.
                                small.opacity-50.text-nowrap now
            div(class=["col-md-9", "col-sm-7", "px-4"])
                //-form(role="form", action="examination_card", method="post")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ul
    each val in myArr
      li= val
```

Make sure that you send data correctly from backend.
The array can be accessed with `data[0].doctorName`
For your case:

```js
   res.render("user-layout",doctors);
```

In PUG:

```
ul
    each doctor in doctors
      li= doctor
```

More about this on:
[Iterations in Pug](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)